# How to build a fat jar for running a spark job on EMR?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I'm trying to run a spark job on EMR. I'm using AMI 3.3.1 which we can see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html) includes scala 2.11.1.

However, spark seems to be compiled against [2.10.x](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

So, what version should I compile my spark job with? Here's my build.sbt:

```
name := "myjar"

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

mainClass := Some("my.EmrPoc")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.0",        
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "0.1",           
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.3.0",
  "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.7",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if x.endsWith(".class") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.endsWith(".properties") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.contains("/resources/") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mailcap") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mimetypes.default") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    if (oldStrategy == MergeStrategy.deduplicate)
      MergeStrategy.first
    else
      oldStrategy(x)
}

assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {_.data.getName == "avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar"}
}
```

The problem is when I run this on EMR, I get an error `Exception in thread "Driver" scala.MatchError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scopt.Read` or something like that (I've terminated the cluster now). So it obviously can't access the `scopt` jar, and I'm wondering whether this is due to me compiling against 2.10.4 but deploying on 2.11.1. But I don't think it is because I uninstalled scala from all instances and reinstalled scala v2.10.4 and got the same message.

So, how can I debug this, and how can I build my jar (the job works fine on my machine in local mode).

Thanks.

Comment: I've used proguard (and sbt-proguard) to do similar things. But I wont lie, every time i use it, it takes tweaking to get it right.

Comment: @RichHenry How is proguard relevant to this?

Comment: I deploy to a Java environment from a Scala project, and Proguard filters my scala-library.jar down to what I use in my module, as the runtime is not available. I've also used similar approaches for things like Scaloid (android projects). Perhaps the problem isn't similar enough, sorry if I caused you any confusion.

Comment: Ah OK. No, in this case I need the particular dependency it's complaining it can't find. I'll bear it in mind though for the future. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a handle to a `scopt` `Class[_]` instance you can do something like `classDef.getResource("/" + classDef.getName.replace(".", "/") + ".class").toExternalForm` to see the name of the jar it was loaded from. Which would hopefully have the version number in it.

Comment: That's supposed to be a class loader that im calling getResource on...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not provide the dependencies that you use. I would recommend to use [sbt assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). All you need to do is create file `/project/assembly.sbt` with

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

and then run `$sbt assembly`. It will create jar which includes all you dependencies. Submit **this jar** and the work is done.